# Fullcalendar not rendering events on calendar init

Tags: fullcalendar

I have this code that works and shows the events on the calendar when I switch views but not when the calendar first initilizes.

```
$('#calWrap').fullCalendar({
       header: {
            right: 'prev,today,next',
            left: 'title'
        },
        editable: true,
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        height: 650,
        events: function(start, end, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/calendar/getEvents',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
                    start: Math.round(start.getTime() / 1000),
                    end: Math.round(end.getTime() / 1000)
                },
                success: function(doc) {
                    var events = doc;
                    callback(events);
                }
            });
        }
});
```

I tried calling `$('#calWrap').fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents' );` in the success handler but that did not work. It's like the events function doesn't get called on the calendar initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#calWrap').fullCalendar({
       header: {
            right: 'prev,today,next',
            left: 'title'
        },
        editable: true,
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        height: 650,
        events:  {
                url: '/calendar/getEvents',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
                    start: Math.round(start.getTime() / 1000),
                    end: Math.round(end.getTime() / 1000)
                }

            }
        }
});
```